# self destructing an android app after certain amount of time

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-lifecycle, system.exit

i currently work on an app that needs a lot of battery in order to support background gps tracking. my experience shows that people just forget about the app runnning in the background when they dont really need the tracking anymore. therefore i setup some code that should close the application after 4 hours.

```
public class SelfDestructor {

    private static SelfDestructor instance;

    private final long IDLE_TIME_UNTIL_AUTO_DESTRUCT = 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 4 hours

    private Handler handler;

    private Runnable closeApp = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };

    public static SelfDestructor getInstance() {
        if (SelfDestructor.instance == null) {
            SelfDestructor.instance = new SelfDestructor();
        }
        return SelfDestructor.instance;
    }

    public void keepAlive() {
        if (handler == null) {
            handler = new Handler();
        }
        handler.removeCallbacks(closeApp);
        handler.postDelayed(closeApp, IDLE_TIME_UNTIL_AUTO_DESTRUCT);
    }
}
```

now in my main activity i call keepAlive().

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SelfDestructor.getInstance().keepAlive();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    SelfDestructor.getInstance().keepAlive();
}
```

now if i set the time to an hours or so and debug the that functionality everything works fine. if i set the time to 4 hours the `System.exit(0);` is never called. i am assuming the app thread with the close callback is just put on hold by the android system after a while and therefore will not be executed anymore while gps will continue to run. any ideas how to properly get this to work?

Comment: Not sure how to achieve that, but adding a notification that can't be removed in the notification bar should be a good way to get your users aware. Make sure that when clicking on the notification, the user is prompted to close the process or keep it running.

Comment: yeah, already implemented that... :)

Comment: I guess that's the best way to handle the problem. Killing a process automatically doesn't seem right to me. At least, I'd make it configurable with a setting for the idle time instead of using a constant. Anyway, as far as I remember, it's possible that the Application will be put in background, which mean, that the code won't be run. You'd have to create an alarm instead. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handler` and `postDelayed` are not suited for long timers. At most they should be used within a few seconds and personally I think I never used one for anything more than 2 seconds.

Said all that, Android have an appropriate class for "stuff that should happen after a long time", it's called AlarmManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

you can get the references to the system service AlarmManager by calling `Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)`

and then set it by calling `am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, IDLE_TIME_UNTIL_AUTO_DESTRUCT, operation)`

the `operation` is a `PendingIntent` to a `BroadcastReceiver` that you register in the `AndroidManifest.xml` via the `<receiver>` tag. Then you do the close application code inside this broadcast receiver.

Also I should add that it's NEVER good to call `System.exit(0);`, as this just destroy the VM without much of a warning. It's a better, more organised/structured shut down if you pass a command to the `Service` that is holding the GPS (I believe you're running a service), then this service will cancel the GPS request, and call `stopSelf();`